# Feedback - Stack Overflow should have a bookmark button

Tags: feature-request, bookmark

How can I save pages that are interesting and may want to use later?

The only way I can think is use the browser's bookmark functionality. It would be good if this functionality is within Stack Overflow so that if you go to your home page you can see all your tagged posts organised into categories.

Maybe this could also have a watch function so that you would be notified of any posts to post that you are watching. Please vote up/down if you think this would be useful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1740850/ejectamenta?tab=favorites

Comment: What is wrong with the browser's functionality? Should every web site reimplement what browsers already do? Maybe you'd like for Stack Overflow to [have an email viewer, too](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/Z/Zawinskis-Law.html)?

Comment: I think that it is useful to have the bookmarks on site as it keeps them in context

Comment: @ejectamenta: So does having a bookmark folder.

Comment: every site should reimplement bookmarklets if its the right thing to do for their users regardless of there being another way to bookmark through the browser, like I said it keeps it in context with the originating webpage, allows notifications etc, so I think it is useful for stackoverflow users, and I don't care if it exists in browsers as well.

Comment: On 2020-05-07, the favourites feature [was renamed to "Bookmarks"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/342029#342029). The text is now *"Bookmark this question."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you ever noticed that star next to any question just below the up/down vote buttons?

This star means *favourite question*. Click it, and this question will be marked as *your personal favourite*, so you will be able to *find that question later easily* in your profile.

You can see anyone's favourites. Here are mine: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4354477/forcebru?tab=favorites. Go to your profile and choose *Favorites* to see all the questions that you have ever put a star on.

Comment: I thought that was just a like button, I shall be using it more often now! would be nice to be able to organise them though

Comment: @ejectamenta, I don't think there is a way to do it, although I agree, that'd be a great feature.

Comment: Perhaps it is time for an update? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today. For example, change to past tense if something needs to be kept.).